# How to resize a table and appending row or column using cursor in JS?

Tags: javascript, angular, html-table

I am trying to create a web app with a table inside. I want two functionalities of this table: (1) When shift clicking on the edge of a cell, a row or a column gets created depending on what side was clicked and (2) when simply clicking and holding down the mouse on an edge of a cell I want the row or column, depending on selected side, to resize that whole row and column. How would one achieve this?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? if yes please provide some codebase.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to be used as a platform to beg for people to complete your homework. This is far too vague. Show us what you've tried already, why it didn't work, why you couldn't do this yourself, why other code samples weren't quite what you were after etc. etc.

Comment: @AbuSufian I have no idea where to even begin. I guess I can set up an HTML table but I believe we all can that and if not it is just a google and 30 second read away to understand.

Comment: @linker I agree, I think people on this platform can be rude and I was a bit harsh there but you can surely see why. It's very frustrating when people jump on here having never tried anything and want a bunch of randoms to just make them websites. 1) Use HTML table, tr, hr, td elements. 2) Use javascript/jquery for detecting button and mouse clicks (there are plenty of examples online). 3) for resizing, again use mouse clicks from step 2.

Comment: @linker And I'm sorry but I don't think you looked hard enough, the internet is scattered with examples, here's about 100 or so that do exactly what you want (they also generously have the code available for every single example): https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=resizable+table and because I'm feeling nice here's [another](https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/making-resizable-table-js.html) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674548/how-to-make-html-table-columns-resizable/41675248)